# How to make Circular Delphi Form perfectly rounded from corners also for Win10

Tags: delphi, winapi, delphi-7

Any ideas how to make my app window look perfectly circular, currently the main form is made circular with this code but its not very smooth from the corners even if I don't place any background image on it:

```
  ShowWindow(Application.Handle, SW_HIDE);
  SetWindowLong(Application.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE,GetWindowLong(Application.Handle, GWL_EXSTYLE) or WS_EX_TOOLWINDOW);
  ShowWindow(Application.Handle, SW_SHOW);
  RRShape := CreateRoundRectRgn(1, 1, Width - 1, height - 1, 100, 100);
   SetWindowRgn(Handle,RRShape,True);
```

Comment: Regions don't support anti-aliasing on curves. Use a [Layered Window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/window-features#layered-windows) instead, and then you can smooth out the curves by using alpha translucency on anti-aliased pixels. I don't recall whether Delphi 7 natively supported the Layered Window APIs or not, so you may have to import and use them manually.

Comment: [How to create a ellipse shaped window with VC++ using win32 API](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1339789/327083).  Not delphi tagged, but the same idea.  Feeling that Y2K nostalgia, I guess?  Brings me back to a time when [Layered windows give the product designers a lot of power to bring "cool" UI closer to reality.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms997507(v=msdn.10)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)